# Missing parameters in cookies WebDriver

Tags: java, cookies, webdriver

I have a problem that i quite don't understand in WebDriver. It seems that the cookie does not get any parameters. The browser used is InternetExplorer

When a do a regular manual log in the cookie looks like this:

```
NAME  mysite
VALUE  ProfileId=104354491&ProfileGuid=129a8bae-dd61-4b3d-9013-66a6c0fc83b8&AccountId=7789931&AccountGuid=3c5d029a-cb9a-4014-9378-188dc0c28d92 
DOMAIN  test.mysite.com
PATH  / 
EXPIRES  30.11.2019 01:00:00
```

But, when i do a log in in WebDriver and print out the cookie information it looks like this:

```
NAME  mysite
VALUE  ProfileId=&ProfileGuid=&AccountId=&AccountGuid= 
DOMAIN  test.mysite.com
PATH  / 
EXPIRES  30.11.2019 01:00:00
```

Why isn't the parameters set? Is there anything that i do wrong when i log in using WebDriver?

This is how the login code looks like

```
//Make sure that user is signed out
DriverUtils.signout(url, internalDriver);
// Type login information and submit form. 
DriverUtils.clearAndType(By.name("pflUsername"), username, internalDriver); 
DriverUtils.clearAndType(By.name("pflPassword"), password, internalDriver);
DriverUtils.mouseClickByLocator(By.cssSelector("fieldset > input.submit"), internalDriver);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, after some testing i finally figured it out. WebDriver went to fast for the cookie to get information. I simply put a Thread.sleep(1000); and then the cookie got its information :)